# How were the whales able to breathe?

Tags: star-trek, the-voyage-home

At the end of the film Gillian is concerned that the whales won't have air, but they were already in an *enclosed* Plexiglass compartment.

**How did the whales breathe in the compartment?**

Comment: it was transparent aluminum! How quaint

Comment: @NKCampbell - No it wasn't; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/why-does-the-aluminium-need-to-be-transparent

Answer (score 5):

The film's [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home_(novel)) indicates that there was a sizeable air-gap at the top of the tank, more than enough for the whales to breathe on their short journey, even if that air wasn't being recycled by the ship's life-support systems (which it almost certainly was).

> *Fighting the instinct to breathe, Jim kicked through the deep water.
>   He broke the surface and flung up his arm to fend off the ceiling. **The
>   sprung seals had allowed most of the air to escape. Only a
>   hands-breadth of airspace remained between the water and the top of
>   the cargo bay.** Gasping, treading water, he tilted his head back so his
>   nose and mouth remained in the air. He took a long, deep breath, and
>   dove again.*

This concurs nicely with the film's [shooting script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/tvh.txt).

> Scene 246: **TOP OF CARGO BAY**
>
> [Kirk breaks the surface, his lungs screaming for air. **Only a few
>   inches remain unflooded.** He gulps air, and dives one last time.]

Answer (score 1):

According to  [this site](https://hawaiihumpbackwhale.noaa.gov/education/whaletrivia.html)

> On average, adult humpbacks surface every 7-15 minutes to breathe but can remain submerged for up to 45 minutes.

That said, there probably wasn't a lot of air in the tank but it was for a short trip to the sun and back with the idea being that the whales would be released into San Francisco Bay upon arrival in the 23rd century.